# Post API search with Python

Tags: python, api, search, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape all news items from this website. They are not showing in the source code: http://www.uvm.dk/aktuelt

I've tried using Firefox' LIVE Http Headers and Chrome's developer tool but still can't figure out what goes on behind the scenes. I'm sure it's pretty simple :-)

I have these information but how do I use them to scrape the wanted news?

http://www.uvm.dk/api/search

Request Method:POST

Connection: keep-alive
PageId=8938bc1b-a673-4513-80d1-e1714ca93d7c&Term=&Years%5B%5D=2017&WorkAreaIds=&SubjectIds=&TemplateIds=&NewsListIds%5B%5D=Emner&TimeSearch%5BEvaluation%5D=&FlagSearch%5BEvaluation%5D=Alle&DepartmentNames=&Letters=&RootItems=&Language=da&PageSize=10&Page=1

Can anyone help?

Comment: perhaps post some code?

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer but some hints.

Your approach with livehttpheaders is a good one. Open the side bar before loading home page, clear all. Then load home page and an article. There usually will a ton of http request because of images, css and js. But you'll be able to find the few ones useful. Usually the very first is for home page and one somewhere below is the article main page. An other interesting one is the one when you click next page.

I like to decouple download (HTTP) and scraping (HTML or JSON or so).
I download to a file with a first script and scrap with a second one.
First because I want to be able to adjust scraping without downloading again and again. Second because I prefer to use bash+curl to download and python+lxml to scrap. If I need information from scraping to go on downloading, my scraping script output it on the console.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried LIVE Http Headers once again and now I got it :-) It turns out I forgot one of the params needed in the POST. 

The result looks like this:

import requests

params = {'xxx': 'xxx', 'xxx': 'xxx', etc}
r = requests.post("http://www.uvm.dk/api/search", data=params)

print (r.text)